# How to assess the impact of an exogenous on endogenous variables in VAR

Tags: r, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I fitted a VAR model that includes an exogenous variable, and I am interested in assessing the impact of the exogenous variable on the endogenous variable.

As far as I know, IRFs (impulse response functions) are used just to assess the impact of an endogenous variable on other endogenous variables. Indeed the `irf` function of the R package `vars` doesn't allow me to use exogenous variables.

However, I am bit confused, because [on a recent report](https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/WP/Issues/2020/10/16/A-Vicious-Cycle-How-Pandemics-Lead-to-Economic-Despair-and-Social-Unrest-49806) I read that authors used VAR (a panel VAR in this case) followed by IRFs to assess the impact of an exogenous dummy variable (Pandemic) on endogenous ones. See picture below.

[image]

Instead I read [on this interesting resource](http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-c/s2013/823/EC823.S2013.nn10.slides.pdf) that

> If there are additional (strictly) exogenous variables in the VAR, the dynamic multiplier functions or transfer functions can be computed. These measure the impact of a unit change in the exogenous variable on the endogenous variables over time. They are generated by fcast compute and graphed with fcast graph.

Unfortunately the above mentioned resource is based on Stata, while I use only R.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it correct that IRFs can't be used to assess the impact of exogenous on endogenous variables?
2. If it is possible to estimate the impact of exogenous on endogenous variables in the framework of VAR, how can I do that (and possibly with which R function can I perform the analysis)?
3. If VAR framework is not suitable for such an analysis, what is the right method to reach the mentioned objective?

Answer (score 4):

You may use the VARXirf from MTS package in R. It helps you to generate IRFs for exogenous variables in R.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MTS/versions/1.0/topics/VARXirf